# Sorting Data from a table, assigning to variable then calling from another file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table inside my larger database that stores quantities and i am able to run a query to call those values (pretty simple) but when I put the following code into my PHP file and call it from another file I always get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a
>   non-object

```
$use = $conn->query("select Quant_Limit from Follett_qty where ISBN =   $isbn");
$rowUser = $use->fetch_assoc();
$follettLimit = $rowUser['Quant_Limit'];

if ($follettLimit==null){
    $follettLimit= 25;
}else {
    $follettLimit= $follettLimit;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"and call it from another file"_?  You haven't defined `$conn` in this code.

Comment: We have a file that allows user to enter an ISBN, then it calls a js file that runs formulas and query, that tells the total quantity we can take, and this worked just fine until we needed to check the Follett_qty table to see if the ISBN was in that table because we could take a different quantity. Now i just get an error no matter what i do to the query (i have the conn called earlier in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, therefore

```
$conn->query("select Quant_Limit from Follett_qty where ISBN =   $isbn");
```

returns `false`. `false` is not an object, so you can't call `fetch_assoc()` on it.

You can see *why* your query is wrong in the error log of your server. It might be that $isbn is not a numeric field, in which case you have to change this to `where ISBN = '$isbn'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to use error reporting. Also suggest you to check query result. Can try something like this

```
$use = $conn->query("select Quant_Limit from Follett_qty where ISBN = '$isbn'") 
    or die($conn->error);
$rowUser = $use->fetch_assoc();
$follettLimit = isset($rowUser['Quant_Limit']) ? $rowUser['Quant_Limit'] : null;
```

Comment: tried this all i get is Quant Limit it does not put out the numerical value of the cell